# ASP.NET MVC2 rendering a partial view with its own controller

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-2

I have the following partial view NewsSummary.ascx used to display a list of news article summaries:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewUserControl<IEnumerable<AkwiMemorial.Models.Article>>" %>
   <table>    
    <% foreach (var item in Model as IEnumerable<AkwiMemorial.Models.Article>)
       { %>

        <tr>            
             <td>
             <strong>
                <%= Html.Encode(String.Format("{0:MMMM dd yyyy}", item.DateCreated)) %>
             </strong>             
            </td>
            <td>
                <%= Html.Encode(item.Abstract) %>
            </td>
           <td> 
              <a class="link1"> <%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ })%></a>                               
            </td>          
        </tr>    
    <% } %>
    </table>
```

My HomeController fetches articles to be displayed and creates an entry in the ViewData dictionary of Index.aspx before it is rendered.  Partial view is then rendered within Index.aspx using Html.RenderPartial with the lists of news articles passed as its model as follows:

```
<% Html.RenderPartial("NewsSummary", ViewData["news"]); %>
```

Now, I already have a NewsController that fetches a news article by a given Id.  With the code as as, clicking on the Details link of each article summary in the NewsSummary partial view invokes an action in my HomeController called Details.  How do I tie this action to the Details method in my NewsController.  I looked into Html.RenderAction but could not determine how it will work for me in this scenario.

Any ideas or am I approaching this the wrong way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should specify the controller as a parameter to `Html.ActionLink` like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Details", "Details", "News", new { /* id=item.PrimaryKey */ }, null) %>
```

Comment: Did that and I now get error:  The resource cannot be found. 
Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /NewsController/Details/2.    Tried specify controller name as "News" but that did not help.  I do not get it.

Comment: Do you have a route set up for that URL?

Comment: Sorry about the goof up in the controller name -- it should be "News" as you indicated. I have updated the answer to reflect this. The next problem you described sounds like a routing issue. You'll need to figure out what is the right URL to hit your controller action and tweak the call to ActionLink accordingly, or consider using RouteLink if it's more appropriate.

Comment: Thanks for help again.  I am using the default route that ships with MVC.  Based on this default route, I should be able to get to NewsController/Details method but this is not happening.  When I click on link, execution does not get to my break point in NewsController.Details(int?).

Comment: Can you please post this problem as a new question? It would improve your chances of getting a good answer.

Comment: Ragesh, I got it to work finally even though execution does not stop at my controller breakpoint.  Think this is another issue I will troubleshoot later.  I was not matching key in parameters dictionary to method argument name.  My NewsController has Details(int newsId) but I was passing new {id = item.Id} instead of new {newsId = item.Id}.  Thanks.